# Not enough space on /tmp but 900mb free on /

Tags: disk-usage, tmp

I get an error saying that I do not have enough space on `/tmp` to download a file. However, I have around 900 Mb of free space on the `/` partition. Is there a way for Ubuntu to actually use this space?

Here is the result of `df -h`:

```
Sys. de fichiers Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev               1.8G     12K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs              351M    1.3M  350M   1% /run
/dev/sda5           19G     18G     0 100% /
none               4.0K       0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none               5.0M       0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none               1.8G    352K  1.8G   1% /run/shm
none               100M     32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2          923M    250M  611M  29% /boot
/dev/sda4           91G     29G   58G  33% /home
overflow           1.0M    448K  576K  44% /tmp
```

and here is the `lsblk` result:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           119.2G
├─sda1 swap     7.5G [SWAP]
├─sda2 ext4     954M /boot
├─sda3            1K      
├─sda4 ext4    92.2G /home
└─sda5 ext4    18.6G /
```

Comment: Your drive is showing 100% utilization. Chances are that they OS is using that last gig of space to run in.. It needs space for its own temp files that grow and shrink.

Comment: @Clément Also look at how you have an 'overflow' type of item for `/tmp`.  Usually, this is also indicative of a 'full disk' as overflow is a `tmpfs` (which sits in RAM, really).  I would suggest a much larger `/` partition as well, at least 30 - 40GB, if you intend to use it and install things on a daily basis outside of `/home`

Comment: If you want a quick fix you can run sudo apt autoclean and you can delete the cache directory from software downloads which may give another gig or so..  sudo apt clean